# How to discard stderr when running a shell function?

Tags: shell

If I run

```
(setq some-variable (shell-command-to-string some-command))
```

...and the execution of the command in `some-command` results in some output sent to `stderr`, this `stderr` output ends up in `some-variable`.

How can I discard the `stderr` output, so that the result consists exclusively of the output sent to `stdout`?  (Better yet would be to capture the `stdout` and `stderr` outputs in separate variables.)

Note that it is not enough to add something like `2>/dev/null` to the command in `some-command`, because the `stderr` output may come from a shell initialization file (e.g. `.bashrc`), and thus would not be captured by the `2>/dev/null` redirection.

Comment: Not really sure about that, but, what about defining setting the `shell-command-default-error-buffer` variable?

Comment: @Nsukami_: this variable apparently applies only to `shell-command` and `shell-command-on-region`...  At any rate, I have not been able to come up with a setting for it that produces a different behavior from the default one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following form instead of `(shell-command-to-string some-command)`:

```
(with-output-to-string
    (with-current-buffer
      standard-output
      (process-file shell-file-name nil '(t nil)  nil shell-command-switch some-command)))
```

That is essentially what `shell-command-to-string` does with the only change that it does discard `stderr`.

You can also substitute the `nil` in `'(t nil)` for some file name to re-direct stderr into that file.

Comment: Thanks!  (I had tried an incorrect version of this, where I mistakenly used `'(t . nil)` instead of `'(t nil)`, who knows where I got that from; unfortunately, the resulting function just worked like before, which gave me no clue as to what I had done wrong.)

Comment: BTW, I tried the second form you mention at the end, but I see nothing in the buffer designated for the `stderr` output (the `stdout` output remains as it should be, though). More specifically, I tried replacing the argument `'(t nil)` with `'(t "*STDERR*")`, and bound `some-command` to something like `"wc -l /dev/null nonexistent"`, which should result in output being sent to both `stdout` and `stderr`.  I tried many variants (e.g. with the `*STDERR*` buffer already open, etc.), but I never saw any output in the designated `stderr` buffer.  Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @kjo I've corrected my answer according to your comment. The error output goes not to a buffer but to a file. This is described in the help of `call-process`. Thanks for you comment (+1).